# Event listener for contact form 7 not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contact-form-7

I have an event listener setup to fire when a user completes a contact form. The JS is supposed to forward my user to another link, but this isn't working on safari unfortunately.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
location = 'my-link.com/pdf';
}, false );
</script>
```

Any ideas why this isn't firing on Safari?

Comment: I have the exact same critical problem. It works in all browsers on Windows, and everything except safari on Mac. Plus there is absolutely no error or warning message anywhere in the developer console.

Comment: The problem seems not to occur with a system like this: `Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4`, but with one like this: `Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.5 Safari/600.5.17`.

Comment: It is an issue of Safari 8 and IOS8, no error but no response. 
Safari 10 cures it.

Did you ever find a workaround or even a reason?